# Flutter load image asset with image file

Tags: image, file, flutter, path, assets

I have a page to allow a user to post something, which includes an image. When the page loads, it loads a `default.png` image and when the user clicks on it, the user is redirected to another page where they can take a picture or choose from a gallery.

The main issue here is that when `my post an item page` loads it looks at the `Image.asset` and see's null. Therefore, `Image.asset` is able to load the `defaultImage`, BUT when the user chooses an image or takes a picture the value that is returned is a `File` and with the `path` attached to it makes it into a `String` (as seen below)

```
child: Image.asset(
                    imageName1?.path ?? defaultImage,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
```

So, `Image.asset` is not able to load this `File.path`

This is the error that I get:

```
Exception has occurred.
FlutterError (Unable to load asset: /data/user/0/com.flutter_project/cache/image_picker4920072427102948834.jpg)
```

I know that `Image.file` works with `file.path`... but do I really need to make an if statement somewhere to ensure proper image display?

Is there some simpler way?

Extra note: when I do a refresh in my visual studio (while my app is running) the image actually loads (as it should)... very weird...
my page is `stateful` and when I pass the `result` (the file from the popped page) I do a `setstate` to `imageName1`

```
final result = await Navigator.push(
context,
MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PhotoPreviewPage()),
);

setState(() {
imageName1 = result;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this below.

```
File imageName1;
```

and once you got the image from the popped route with the selected image result from the navigator.

```
final result = await Navigator.push(
  context,
  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => PhotoPreviewPage()),
);

setState(() {
  imageName1 = File(result.path);
});
```

In the build method.

```
(imageName1 == null)
    ? ClipOval(
       child: SizedBox(
       width: 120.0,
       height: 120.0,
       child: CachedNetworkImage(
         imageUrl: (widget.user.userImg != null) ? widget.user.userImg ?? '' : AssetImages.course,
         placeholder: (context, url) => Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
         errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Image.asset(AssetImages.smallLoader),
         fit: BoxFit.fill,
        ),
      ),
     )
     : ClipOval(
         child: Image.file(
           imageName1,
           width: 120,
           height: 120,
           fit: BoxFit.cover,
         ),
       ),
```